# How can I save an output from my function?

Tags: r, function

I am stucked right now. I need to find correlations of some files and I don´t know how to save my results. There must be some kind of very small problem which I don´t see right now.

```
correl<-function(prah=0){
      for (i in dir()) {
        list<-read.csv(i)
        subset<-(list[(!is.na(list$sulfate & list$nitrate)),])
        correlation<-cor(subset$sulfate,subset$nitrate)
        rows<-nrow(subset)
        results<-if(prah<=rows){correlation}else if(prah>rows){NULL}
      }
      return(results)
    }
    x<-correl(prah=0)
```

The function itself works pretty well. I can calculate correlation as I need, but it is impossible to save it. The result should look at the end like this.

```
> cr<-correl(prah=150)
> head(cr)
[1] -0.01895754 -0.14051254 -0.04389737 -0.06815956 -0.12350667 -0.07588814
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are looking for functions that save data. See `?write.csv`, `?write.table` or even `?MASS::write.matrix`

Comment: Try `return(results)` rather than `print(results)`

Comment: See ?save in console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the output, you should put your `result` outside `for` loop and at the bottom of your function body, e.g.,

```
correl<-function(prah=0){
  results <- list()
  for (i in dir()) {
    list<-read.csv(i)
    subset<-(seznam[(!is.na(list$sulfate & list$nitrate)),])
    correlation<-cor(subset$sulfate,subset$nitrate)
    rows<-nrow(subset)
    if(prah<=rows) {
      results[[length(results)+1]]<-correlation
    }
    else {
      results[[length(results)+1]] <- NULL}
  }
  return(results)
}
```